# Working with Java constructor and answer is not returning the correct output

Tags: java, constructor

I am working on a code for school and part of our topic is on the use of constructors.

I have a constructor implemented into my code and when I run it, I am getting most of the output correct. The string arguments are returning a "null" instead of the string values I have entered. I feel like the error is in my constructor under the dog class, but I don't know where to go from here.

```
public class Dog {

    // instance variables
    private String type;
    private String breed;
    private String name;
    private String topTrick;

    // constructor
    public Dog(String type, String breed, String name) {

    }

    // methods


    public void setTopTrick(String topTrick) {
        this.topTrick = topTrick;
    }

    // method used to print Dog information
    public String toString() {
        String temp = "\nDOG DATA\n" + name + " is a " + breed +
                ", a " + type + " dog. \nThe top trick is : " +
                topTrick + ".";
        return temp;
    }

}

public class Corgi extends Dog {

    // additional instance variables
    private int weight;
    private int age;

    // constructor
    public Corgi(String type, String breed, String name, int pounds, int years) {

        // invoke Dog class (super class) constructor
        super(type, breed, name);
        weight = pounds;
        age = years;
    }

    // mutator methods
    public int getWeight() {
        return weight;
    }

    public void setWeight(int weight) {
        this.weight = weight;
    }

    public int getAge() {
        return age;
    }

    public void setAge(int age) {
        this.age = age;
    }

    // override toString() method to include additional dog information
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return (super.toString() + "\nThe Corgi is " + age +
                " years old and weighs " + weight + " pounds.");
    }

}
public class Driver {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    Corgi spot = new Corgi("herding group","Golden Retriever" ,"Frank", 0, 0);



    spot.setTopTrick("Hoop Jumping");
    System.out.print(spot.toString());

    }

}
```

My output is DOG DATA
null is a null, a null dog. 
The top trick is : Hoop Jumping.
The Corgi is 0 years old and weighs 0 pounds.

Comment: you need to set values in Dog constructor too, like this.type=type;

Comment: In the constructor of `Dog`, you need to set the attributes to the parameters, e.g. `this.type = type;`.

Answer (score 3):

While you are passing the constructor values for type, breed and name, you are not assigning them to class variables.

Easiest fix in my opinion would be to change:

```
 public Dog(String type, String breed, String name) {

}
```

to

```
 public Dog(String type, String breed, String name) {
  this.type=type;
  this.breed=breed;
  this.name=name;

}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
 public Dog(String type, String breed, String name) {
     this.type = type;
     this.breed = breed;
     this.name = name;
 }
```

The difference between "this.type" and "type" is, that the first refers to the object's type that you are creating, the latter is the parameter handed over via the constructor parameter.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you are calling "super(type, breed, name)" but in parent constructor you are not assigning it to the instance of the object,So because the value of "type", "breed" and "name" is null initially, it is returning the same.

Best way to do it is:

```
public Dog(String type, String breed, String name) {
     this.type = type;
     this.breed = breed;
     this.name = name;
 }
```

where the values are assigned to the instance of that object.

Comment: if you have any doubt, you can ask me here. And if you like my answer please upvote... :)